# Importing csv formatted for excel into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am receiving datafiles from 2 different people and the files are coming through with different formats despite both users using the same system and the same browser.

I would like to be able to make my code smart enough to read either format but so far I have been unsuccessful.

The data coming through I am having issues with looks like this

```
+----------------+---------------+--------------+
| Customer Name  | Customer code | File Ref     |
+----------------+---------------+--------------+
| ACCOUNT SET UP | ="35"         | R2I0025715   |
+----------------+---------------+--------------+
| Xenox          | ="4298"       | ="913500999" |
+----------------+---------------+--------------+
```

and the data that is importing cleanly looks like this

```
+----------------+---------------+------------+
| Customer Name  | Customer code | File Ref   |
+----------------+---------------+------------+
| ACCOUNT SET UP | 35            | R2I0025715 |
+----------------+---------------+------------+
| Xenox          | 4298          | 913500999  |
+----------------+---------------+------------+
```

I am trying to import the data with the following code `pd.read_csv(f, encoding='utf-8', dtype={"Customer Name": "string", "Customer code": "string", "File Ref": "string"})`

A workaround that I am using is opening each csv in excel, and saving. But when this involves hundreds of files, it isn't really a workaround.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of csv files?

Comment: Are the entries in the dataframe strings?

Comment: @Angus Campbell yes

Comment: @corralien yes I could but I would need to amend them - is there a way to upload them here?

Comment: @Zabman if you open up the .csv file in a text editor, you can copy and paste the problematic portion of the .csv file into your question

Comment: @Derek O I have ammended my question to include the first few lines of the good and bad files

Answer (score 1):

You could use the standard `strip()` function to remove leading and trailing `=` and `"` characters on all of your columns.

For example:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Customer Name' : ['ACCOUNT SET UP', 'Xenox', 'ACCOUNT SET UP', 'Xenox'],
    'Customer Code': ['="35"', '="4298"', '35', '4298'], 
    'File Ref': ['R2I0025715', '="913500999"', 'R2I0025715', '913500999']
}  
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 

for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].str.strip('="')

print(df)
```

Giving you:

```
    Customer Name Customer Code    File Ref
0  ACCOUNT SET UP            35  R2I0025715
1           Xenox          4298   913500999
2  ACCOUNT SET UP            35  R2I0025715
3           Xenox          4298   913500999
```

If you just want to apply it to specific columns, use:

```py
for col in ['Customer Code', 'File Ref']:
    df[col] = df[col].str.strip('="')
```

Answer (score 0):

**My Solution:**

```
import re
import pandas as pd

def removechar(x):
    x = str(x)
    out = re.sub('="', '', x)
    return(out)

def removechar2(x):
    x = str(x)
    out = re.sub('"', '', x)
    out = int(out) #could use float(), depends on what you want
    return(out)

#then use applymap from pandas
```

**Example:**

```
datas = {'feature1': ['="23"', '="24"', '="23"', '="83"'], 'feature2': ['="23"', '="2"', '="3"', '="23"']}  
test = pd.DataFrame(datas) # Example dataframe

test
Out[1]: 
  feature1 feature2
0    ="23"    ="23"
1    ="24"     ="2"
2    ="23"     ="3"
3    ="83"    ="23"

#applymap my functions
test = test.applymap(removechar)
test = test.applymap(removechar2)

test
Out[2]: 
  feature1 feature2
0       23       23
1       24        2
2       23        3
3       83       23
#fixed
```

Note you could probably do it just one line of applymap and one function running re.sub, try googling and reading the documentation for re.sub, this was something quick I whipped up.